# Firefox ESR 31.2.0 on Gentoo Linux mangles ligatures "ff", "fl", "fi" and "ffl"

Tags: gentoo, fonts, firefox

I am running Firefox ESR 31.2.0 on Gentoo Linux on an AMD64 computer with 8 GB RAM. Today I noticed that quite often, when Firefox encounters the text sequences "ff", "fi", "fl" and "ffl", it merges them into an Unicode ligature glyph. However, it seems like my computer is picking up the wrong glyph, and as a result I end up with weird characters all over my open pages. This happens to both the rendering engine as well as the program's UI.

This, for example, is how it looks like when I write "ff fl fi ffl" on the address bar.

[image: Weird ligature switcheroo]

Any idea of what's going on?

Comment: I'm having the same issue on Debian. I have only seen it on Wikipedia. Have you managed to fix this yet?

Comment: Which Debian? It seems to have fixed itself, probably a bug that was fixed on an update or maybe from one time I had to rebuild everything due to failing drivers.

Comment: What do you mean "which Debian"? [*The* Debian](http://www.debian.org/). Anyways, I'm running the testing branch so maybe that's what messed something up.

Comment: Testing was the answer indeed. I guess you could wait for the bugfix in your case.

Comment: I have this problem under Gentoo. As far as I can tell, it appeared when I installed some fonts, but uninstalling them did not help. What solved it for you?

Comment: Nevermind - restarted Firefox and it went away.

Answer (score 0):

The solution described in https://bbs.archlinux.org/viewtopic.php?id=136771 appears to work for me.

Create a file called `70-no-embedded-bitmaps.conf` or similar (not sure about the naming) in `/etc/fonts/conf.avail`, with the following content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
    <match target="font" >
        <edit name="embeddedbitmap" mode="assign">
            <bool>false</bool>
        </edit>
    </match>
</fontconfig>
```

Then enable it with `eselect fontconfig list |grep no-embedded-bitmaps` and `eselect fontconfig enable [number]`. You may have to regenerate the fontconfig cache with `fc-cache -r`.